# Run Kafka Standalone in Docker Container on production env for CDC

Tags: linux, docker, apache-kafka, debezium, change-data-capture

I have to implement Change Data Capture (CDC) and deliver changes from Postgres DB to Data Lake (AWS S3).
I want to implement CDC with Debezium and Kafka.
This is data flow: Postgres --> Debezium --> Kafka --> S3

I have about 5GB (about 90 tables) of data daily, that will be moved to Kafka.

- High availability is not the issue - if Kafks or Server fails, we will simply rerun.
- Scalability is not the issue - we don't have such a big load.
- Fault Tolerance is not the issue also.
- Speed is also not important

I want to manually (AWS MSK is not an option because of price) run Kafka **Standalone** (1 Broker) on **production** in **docker** containers to deliver data to S3.

According to that, I have a few questions:

- Is my architecture OK for solving the CDC problem?
- Is it better to run Kafka in a Docker Container or install Kakfa manually on a Virtual Server (EC2)
- Is My solution OK for production?
- Data Loss: If Kafka experiences a failure, will Debezium retain the captured changes and transfer them to Kafka once it is back online?
- Data Loss: If Debezium experiences a failure, will the system resume reading changes from the point where it stopped before the failure occurred?  (not sure if this question is ok)
- Any solutions or recommendations for my problem?

Comment: Looks like the SO mods are gonna shut this one down, so just a note that you'll perhaps get more help over on https://old.reddit.com/r/apachekafka.

Comment: If the single kafka server fails, and you rerun, you'll end up with duplicate data... Debezium stores its own state in kafka, so it cannot just resume itself

Comment: @RobinMoffatt thanks for letting me know. What is wrong with my question?
Is my solution ok for my business needs?

Comment: @OneCricketeer Can You explain how it can happen? When I rerun Kafka, will Debezium check the point where it stopped before the failure and continue reading the transaction log from that point?
Is my solution ok for my business needs?

Comment: My point is that you have not mentioned your data storage solution; Docker containers are not persistent, by default. Debezium itself is stateless. Also Kafka defaults to store data in /tmp directory, so if you used a VM and that were to restart, you'd also lose data that way.

Comment: @OneCricketeer do you have some proposal/idea for solving this? 
Can I make docker persistent or install Kafka on the VM and change Kafka store to something different than /tmp?